# KEY up not firing in all texarea while using RXJS keyup event

Tags: angular, rxjs

So im working with RXJS input key up event on a textarea

```
@ViewChild('querySearchInput') querySearchInput: ElementRef;


 fromEvent(this.querySearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
        map((event: any) => {
          return event.target.value;
        }), filter(res => res.length > 2), debounceTime(2000), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((text: string) => {
         console,log(text);

        });


  <textarea class="form-control mb-3 custom-height" #querySearchInput [ngClass]="{'error':submitted && !checkProblem(), 'animate-shake':shake,'half':autoSuggestStart }" id="problem" placeholder="Type your issue here (minimum characters 15) ..." [maxlength]="maxChars"
```

i have multiple categories where you can enter the issue you are facing

RXJS keyup doesn't fire for some of the textarea in other categories the but if i use normal keyup function it works everywhere,im an absolute beginner in angular any guidance will be very helpful

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoV8W.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMgiZ.png)

Comment: How do you know it doesn't fire in all keyups? have you tried putting a console log under  `map((event: any) => {console.log(event); return event.target.value;})`?

Comment: @Ashish thank you for the swift response ,yes i have tried that and it doesn't fire on some of the categories, check screen shot above

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand by the screenshot, in which scenarios did it not fire?

Comment: so i have 5 categories  like mouse issue or laptop issue etc , where user can select these categories and enter problem description in the textarea i have a keyup event binded using view child decorator on the textarea it works...the problem is it works on some categories and some other it doesnt fire ,the above screen shot shows its firing for some category textarea  and for some it doesnt even respond

Comment: Are all the `textarea`s having the same ref variable name in template? `querySearchInput`?

Comment: Yes I am using the same textarea in all the categories ,Not sure where im going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I believe, having `@ViewChild()` is the culprit here, since you have multiple references with the same ref name, you should use `@ViewChildren()`

```
@ViewChildren('querySearchInput') querySearchInput: ElementRef[];


ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('Temp reference variable => ', this.querySearchInput);

  this.querySearchInput.forEach((ref: ElementRef) => {
    fromEvent(ref.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map((event: any) => {
          console.log('event trigerrred', event);
          return event.target.value;
        }),
        filter(res => res.length > 2),
        debounceTime(2000),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe((text: string) => {
        console.log(text);
      });
  });
}
```

Please see a Dummy here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vouy1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I also feel that there would be a need to destroy these registered events.
You can use `takeUntil()` and fulfill it in `ngOnDestroy()`

Comment: @asish thanks for the response im only getting one element  in the array ,so i dont think there is duplication and view children is also not working ,attached the screen shot above of the returned array

Comment: @BHL: Are your `textarea` conditional? do they have `ngIf`? And how do you have just one ref in array? when you say you have five textareas?

Comment: Yes they are conditional , dont have five text area same one shows up for all categories

Comment: @BHL: Can you please add more code, so that your question is more understandable. I am going off now, someone can answer or else will see tomorrow